# cant place widget on frame tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

so i have this code

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
frame1 = Frame(master)
Label(frame1, text="First Name").grid(row=0)
Label(frame1, text="Last Name").grid(row=1)

e1 = Entry(frame1)
e2 = Entry(frame1)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

mainloop()
```

it just appear a blank windows, like this
[nothing appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUB9F.jpg)

but, if place widget in frame like this

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
frame1 = Frame(master)
Label(master, text="First Name").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="Last Name").grid(row=1)

e1 = Entry(master)
e2 = Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

mainloop()
```

it appear like this
[It appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdGn9.jpg)

please help me to place widget on frame
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `pack` (or `grid` / `place`) the frame.

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
frame1 = Frame(master)
Label(frame1, text="First Name").grid(row=0)
Label(frame1, text="Last Name").grid(row=1)

e1 = Entry(frame1)
e2 = Entry(frame1)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

frame1.pack()  # <------
mainloop()
```